# Customize list item bullets using CSS

Tags: css, size, html-lists, listitem

Is it possible to change the size of an `<li>` element's *bullet*?

*Take a look at the code below:*

```
li {
    list-style: square; /* I want to change the size of this squared bullet. */
}
```

I can't seem to find any way to achieve that.

Comment: Do you mean just the 'bullet' part of it, and not the text contents of the `li` element yeah?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You mean altering the size of the bullet, I assume? I believe this is tied to the font-size of the li tag. Thus, you can blow up the font-size for the LI, then reduce it for an element contained inside. Kind of sucks to add the extra markup - but something like:

```
li {font-size:omgHuge;}
li span {font-size:mehNormal;}
```

Alternately, you can specify an image file for your list bullets, that could be as big as you want:

```
ul{
  list-style: square url("38specialPlusP.gif");
 }
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp

Comment: Right - as @dan mentioned - with a custom image you will need to alter your padding to accomodate.

Comment: In that school of thought, I think you could also use CSS :before to create a square div, instead of the bullet, if it's square bullets you're after.

Comment: I looked this question up because I have a bullet icon I'd like to apply as my custom style for bullets. But the original file is huge. I'd like to have the browser resize it so I don't have to download the image, resize, re-upload, and re-hotlink. https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/bullet-points/64/Bulletpoint_Bullet_Listicon_Shape_Bulletfont_Glyph_Typography_Bullet_Point_Customshape_Wingding_Custom_Star_Four_Square_Decoretive-512.png

Comment: My two cents @Musixauce3000: I took a required web design class called "Web Graphics". The first day they taught us that the smaller you can make your files the better. Having browser resize the site consumes the users' bandwidth (quite detrimental if they browse on mobile), resulting in slow page load time and eating up the users' data plan. Best practice is currently (Aug. 2016) to download the file, modify it, then upload the modified file--exactly what you said you wanted to avoid. I wish there was an easier way. Great question though.

Answer (score 50):

#### UPDATE

Use [`::marker` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker). See [@RobertKegel answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70928342/5318303).

---

#### Legacy answer

<sub>*Based on [@dzimney answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34570803/5318303) and similar to [@Crisman answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38164530/5318303) (but different)*</sub>

That answer is good but has **indention issue** (bullets appear **inside of `li` scope**). Probably you don't want this. See simple example list below (this is a default HTML list):

- *Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei cum offendit partiendo iudicabit. At mei quaestio honestatis, duo dicit affert persecuti ei. Etiam nusquam cu his, nec alterum posidonium philosophia te. Nec an purto iudicabit, no vix quod clita expetendis.*
- *Quem suscipiantur no eos, sed impedit explicari ea, falli inermis comprehensam est in. Vide dicunt ancillae cum te, habeo delenit deserunt mei in. Tale sint ex his, ipsum essent appellantur et cum.*

But if you use the mentioned answer the list will be like below (ignoring the size of the bullets):

• <del>*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei cum offendit partiendo iudicabit. At mei quaestio honestatis, duo dicit affert persecuti ei. Etiam nusquam cu his, nec alterum posidonium philosophia te. Nec an purto iudicabit, no vix quod clita expetendis.*</del>

• <del>*Quem suscipiantur no eos, sed impedit explicari ea, falli inermis comprehensam est in. Vide dicunt ancillae cum te, habeo delenit deserunt mei in. Tale sint ex his, ipsum essent appellantur et cum.*</del>

---

**So I recommend this approach that resolves the issue:**

```css
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;    /* It's needed for setting position to absolute in the next rule. */
}

li::before {
    content: '■';
    position: absolute;
    left: -0.8em;          /* Adjust this value so that it appears where you want. */
    font-size: 1.1em;      /* Adjust this value so that it appears what size you want. */
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei cum offendit partiendo iudicabit. At mei quaestio honestatis, duo dicit affert persecuti ei. Etiam nusquam cu his, nec alterum posidonium philosophia te. Nec an purto iudicabit, no vix quod clita expetendis.</li>
    <li>Quem suscipiantur no eos, sed impedit explicari ea, falli inermis comprehensam est in. Vide dicunt ancillae cum te, habeo delenit deserunt mei in. Tale sint ex his, ipsum essent appellantur et cum.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This should be the right answer. Works like a charm

Comment: Just to add this, you may also need to set the `font-family` to ensure the bullet is rendered correctly. For example, some fonts render circular bullets as squares.

Comment: The problem with this approach is then the bullet is no longer vertically centered on the text.

Answer (score 25):

You can wrap the contents of the `li` in another element such as a `span`. Then, give the `li` a larger `font-size`, and set a normal `font-size` back on the `span`:

http://jsfiddle.net/RZr2r/

```
li {
    font-size: 36px;
}
li span {
    font-size: 18px;
}
<ul>
    <li><span>Item 1</span></li>
    <li><span>Item 2</span></li>
    <li><span>Item 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks. after researching more, this seems to be the only solution, provided I don't want to use a background image instead of the <li> element.

Comment: This works well. But is there any way to do this but have the middle of the text vertically align with the middle of the bullet?

Comment: This seems to be the most maintainable and least work. Two lines of CSS and a search and replace in the HTML. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

Depending on the level of IE support needed, you could also use the :before selector with the bullet style set as the content property.

```
li {  
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: small;
}

li:before {
  content: '\2022';
  font-size: x-large;
}
```

You may have to look up the [HTML ASCII](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) for the bullet style you want and use a [converter](http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html) for CSS Hex value.

Comment: this is not enough: the `:before` pseudo-element will be in the text flow, not separated on the left, so if a list item has 2+ lines, this will look ugly

Answer (score 14):

You can use the ::marker CSS pseudo-element to style the number or bullet of a list. Currently, January 2022, Safari support is limited to color and font-size.

Example:

```css
::marker {
  color: red;
  font-size: 2rem
}

ul > li::marker {
  color: blue;
}

ol > li::marker {
  font-size: 1rem
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Step One</li>
  <li>Step Two</li>
  <li>Step Three</li>
</ul>
 
<ol>
  <li>Wake up</li>
  <li>Code</li>
  <li>Sleep</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way of changing the size of the bullets would be:

1. Disabling the bullets altogether
2. Re-adding the custom bullets with the help of `::before` pseudo-element.

**Example:**

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
  display:          inline-block;
  vertical-align:   middle;
  width:            5px;
  height:           5px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-right:     8px;
  content:          ' '
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>first element</li>
  <li>second element</li>
</ul>
```

No markup changes needed

Comment: first, it's `:before`, not `::before`; second, same problem as with dzimney's answer: the pseudo-element will be in the text flow, not separated on the left, so if a list item has 2+ lines, this will look ugly

Comment: The **pseudo elements** are written with double colon, instead of single colon notation (as **pseudo classes** are). I agree, however, with your second point.

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing that out. Things have changed since I've read docs about pseudo elements (long ago), the double colon notation is indeed recommended for pseudo elements, although the old single colon notation is supported for backward compability (https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)

Comment: This solution is good - plenty of control over display of the bullet. You could make the bullets circles by just adding ``border-radius: 100%``

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean the size of the bullet at the start of each list item. If that's the case, you can use an image instead of it:

```
list-style-image:url('bigger.gif');
list-style-type:none;
```

If you meant the actual size of the `li` element, then you can change that as normal with `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 3):

### Use the Free Unicode Icons, Symbols, & Emoticons Built into Browsers Instead!

You dont need all those custom fonts, links to files, CDN's, Bootstrap tricks, Font-Awesome, or even JavaScript! **There are *THOUSANDS OF ICONS* built into browsers that are free to use as bullets in your CSS just by typing a small number into your code. Its called UNICODE!**

Here is a **Unicode version**. This one allows you to drop in any text symbol or emoticon you like into your CSS bullet list. All you need is the Unicode "code point" value which is free...and there are thousands of icons native to modern browsers!! Just search for *unicode code points* and paste whatever icon you need into your CSS as so.

Note: **Be careful and pick a font-face in CSS that has a range of Unicode glyphs!**  Most modern fonts support a wide range of glyphs that support most *upper plane Unicode* code points. But you might stumble on some that do not.

```
<style>
#html_list{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 1em;
    list-style: none;
}
#html_list li::before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "\2023";/* <<< ADD YOUR UNICODE ICON NUMBER HERE */
    color: #114f66;
    font-size: 3rem;
    line-height: 0;
    padding: 0 .1em 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    top: .2em;
    left: 0em;
}
#html_list li {
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: .2em 0em .2em 0em;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
</style>

<ul id="html_list">
    <li><a href="#">Area 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Area 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Area 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

The main problem in using Unicode or text symbols in lists is **resizing**. Even after you have stripped away height, line-height, padding, and margins, the symbol has spacing after resizing it using font-size. Most of this is based on the font you choose.

I've designed the best possible solution above that keeps the Unicode bullet text and its style separate from the rest of the list text using a pseudo-element. This idea allows you to remove the default list-style bullet in the parent unordered list, insert a new Unicode bullet into a `::before` pseudo-element. You can then resize and reposition it as you like. Once you have lined up your sized bullets with the list text, you can then start padding or sizing your list text as you need and the bullets should move with it.

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not want to wrap the content in your `<li>`s with `<span>`s, you can also use `:before` like this:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  }
li {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
li:before {
  content: '\2022';
  line-height: 16px; /*match the li line-height for vertical centered bullets*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
li.huge:before {
  font-size: 30px;
}

li.small:before {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Adjust your font sizes on the `:before` to whatever you would like.

```html
<ul>
  <li class="huge">huge bullet</li>
  <li class="small">smaller bullet</li>
  <li class="huge">multi line item with custom<br/> sized bullet</li>
  <li>normal bullet</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Things have obviously changed a little since 2011. Today CSS offers two simple and well-supported ways of customising the bullets in an unordered list.

The most recent one is the [`::marker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker) pseudo-element. It allows you to apply styles directly to any marker, be it a bullet or a number. See [Robert Kegel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70928342/2652785) for a more detailed description of that.

The other method is deceptively simple. You just set the `list-style-type` property on your `ul` to a quoted string and choose whatever Unicode character tickles your fancy. In this example, I've chosen character `U+25A0` (Black Square), which is bigger than the standard square bullet:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: square;
}
ul.big-bullets {
  list-style-type: "■  ";
}
```

```html
<ul class="big-bullets">
  <li>Check out my square bullets!</li>
  <li>They are big, and perfectly aligned.</li>
  <li>And all it took was one very simple line of CSS.</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>They <em>are</em> big bullets.</li>
  <li>I'm a little jealous.</li>
</ul>
```

The ability to set a string on the `list-style-type` property has been around for many years, but browser support took a while to catch up. It's now over 92% according to [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_list-style-type_string).

Now, you may be thinking you'd rather just apply a `font-size` than delve into obscure Unicode characters, and in that case, you'd go for the `::marker` method. But keep in mind, those bullet characters are only designed to line up nicely when used at the same font size as the rest of the text. IMHO, choosing the right bullet character in the first place is the way to go. If you want more fine-grained control, you can, of course, use both techniques together.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li id="bigger"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>

  <style>
     #bigger .li {height:##px; width:##px;}
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an image to change the actual size or form of the bullet itself:

You can use a background image with appropriate padding to nudge content so it doesn't overlap:

```
list-style-image:url(bigger.gif);
```

or

```
background-image: url(images/bullet.gif);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your `<li>` content in a `<span>` or other tag, you may change the font size of the `<li>`, which will change the size of the bullet, then reset the content of the `<li>` to its original size. You may use `em` units to resize the `<li>` bullet proportionally.

For example:

```
<ul>
    <li><span>First item</span></li>
    <li><span>Second item</span></li>
</ul>
```

Then CSS:

```
li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

li * {
    font-size: initial;
}
```

A more complex example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>List Item Bullet Size</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
ul.disc li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

ul.square li {
    list-style-type: square;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

li * {
    font-size: initial;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>First</h1>
<ul class="disc">
    <li><span>First item</span></li>
    <li><span>Second item</span></li>
</ul>

<h1>Second</h1>
<ul class="square">
    <li><span>First item</span></li>
    <li><span>Second item</span></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Results in:

[image: Result of markup]

Comment: Code-only solutions are considered poor-quality content.  Please add some description about *why* this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution that I think works really well and gets around all of the pitfalls of custom symbols. The main problem with the li:before solution is that if list-items are longer than one line will not indent properly after the first line of text. By using text-indent with a negative padding we can circumvent that problem and have all the lines aligned properly:

```
ul{
    padding-left: 0; // remove default padding
}

li{
    list-style-type: none;  // remove default styles
    padding-left: 1.2em;    
    text-indent:-1.2em;     // remove padding on first line
}

li::before{
    margin-right:     0.5em; 
    width:            0.7em; // margin-right and width must add up to the negative indent-value set above
    height:           0.7em;

    display:          inline-block;
    vertical-align:   middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: orange;
    content:          ' '
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method moves the disc out of the text flow where the original disc was, but is adjustable.

```
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    
    li{ 
        position: relative;
      }
    li:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: .1rem;
        left: -.8em;
        content: '\2022';
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen this technique mentioned. It basically allows you to have a "dot" any size you want. It uses a round border to draw a circle.

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 2.5rem;
}

li:before {
    content: " ";
    border: 1rem solid #1b1b1b;
    border-radius: 99rem;
    height: 0; /* it's all controlled by the border */
    width: 0;
    margin-top: -0.4rem;
    margin-left:  -2.5rem;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add ::marker after your li tag like so

```
ul li::marker{
font-size:2px;
}
```

and done.