# How can I increase the bullet size in a li?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, html-lists

The bullets in IE8 are so small, I tried changing the font-size, but that didn't work.
Code:

```
<ul style="padding:0; margin:0; margin-left:20px;">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to do this without using an image for the bullet?

Comment: i'm asking about some fix ...

Comment: yes i would like to make the bullets larger like firefox

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customize list item bullets using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457059/customize-list-item-bullets-using-css)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could do this in an IE8 conditional comment...

```
ul {
   list-style: none;
}

ul li:before {
   content: "•";
   font-size: 170%; /* or whatever */
   padding-right: 5px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qm3d/).

In IE7, you could prepend the bullet via JavaScript and style it accordingly.

Comment: it works fine in ie8 but not in ie7, cuz before doesn't work in ie7

Comment: @user964104: Yep. However, your question includes *The bullets in IE8...*

Comment: @alex; use hex value for bullet in your css. It's better because in some cases symbols is not working.

Comment: @sandeep: I'd use `\2022` in that case.

Comment: Good idea. I would add a `vertical-align:bottom;` in the `before` selectors to make the bullet looking better.

Comment: It's an idea I like if you want a different char as a list bullet. It won't work in the event that you'd like an ordered list to have larger fonts. In that event, adding a div in the li with different/default font values.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do:

```css
li::marker{
   content:"\25A0";
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   color: black;
   vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: code is working but `;` is missing after `content:"\25A0"` and `font-size: 1.5rem`

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer doesn't seem to natively support sizing of the bullets from `list-style-type` with `font-size` as Firefox and Chrome appear to. I do not know if this is a known problem or bug.

There are workarounds, but sometimes an image is the quickest and more widely supported "fix".

Answer (score 0):

IE8+ does scale the bullets but not for every font size.
My fix is based on the fact the bullets for Verdana are larger than for Arial. I use css to set Verdana for `li`, at the same time I add extra spans around `li`'s contents to keep the original font. Also, as Verdana can makes the lines higher, I may need to use line-height to make up for that, but that depends on the browser.
Also I can use bigger font size for `li` to make the bullets even larger, then I'll have to use still smaller line-height.

```
ul {
    font: 12px Arial;
}
ul li {
    font-family: Verdana;
    line-height: 120%;
} /* font-size: 14px; line-height: 100%; */
ul li span {
    font: 12px Arial;
}

<ul>
    <li><span>item 1</span>
    <li><span>item 2</span>
</ul>
```