# Increase size of list-style-bullet type

Tags: css, html-lists

Is there a way to increase the size of *just* the bullet list-style-type using CSS?  I don't want to increase the size of the bullet text, just the bullet type.  I can't use images or JavaScript either.  It has to be something I can embed inside `<style>` tags within the `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Might not work in old version of IE.

`li:before{ content:'\00b7'; font-size:100px; }`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GuzCm/1/)

**For IE6:**

Without javascript or images, I would recommend putting a `<span>&#183;</span>` in the beginning of every list item and styling that.

Comment: +1 great example (the vertical-align:middle was actually CRUCIAL here. nice)! also insted of "\00b7" can use "•" :)

Comment: I generally use the escaped hex values, as I've had some trouble before with using the symbol. For example, this: `span:before{content:""";}` doesn't work, but this: `span:before{content:"\0022";}` does.

Comment: Thanks, bookcasey. Excellent solution, although I can't use `:before` since its for an IE6 only website.

Comment: Without javascript or images, with support needed for IE6, I would recommend putting a `<span>&#183;</span>` in the beginning of every list item and styling that.

Comment: Thanks bookcasey.  Yeh, thats the answer.  post it so I can award you the points.  it's ugly but it will work... ;)  just wanted to know if there was cleaner way of styling the bullet type. Thanks everybody

Comment: The real bummer is that you have to support IE6. :-) I reflected the new solution in my answer.

Comment: Wow. I've never heard of an IE6 ONLY website. So for those on other browsers, do you have a pop up with a link to legacy download of IE6?

Comment: @Dean_Wilson at the time, the company had customers who could have been using IE6, so we had to support it.  Glad those days are over :)

Comment: unfortunately 00b7 isn't round.. becomes obvious if you increase the font size a lot.

Comment: I don't think this completely solves the problem.  This changes the line height for the first line only.  This is a problem if you have a multiple line item.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/1yjcg59c/

Answer (score 10):

I have had to do something similar. My method was to add a span tag around the text within the li:

```
<li><span>Item 1</span></li>
<li><span>Item 1</span></li>
```

Then you can increase the font-size of you li and reduce the font size of your span:

```
li {
  font-size: 20px;
}
li span {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

You may need to adjust line-heights and margins to accommodate for the extra li sizing. But this method will also allow you to colour the bullets separate from text.

Comment: This works nicely for styling the bullets in emails since you can use in-line styles for them. Oh the horror of HTML emails! :)

Comment: Simple and nice solution that allows you to easily manipulate the color of the bullets.

Answer (score 9):

To increase the size of the bullet you can use

```
li::marker 
{
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

and to change bullet character, the content property will work

```
li::marker 
{
    content: '\2746';
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say you can't use images, do you mean you  can't edit the `li` tags to add images, or that you can't use an image at all?

On the `li` elements, you can set the `list-style-image` property.

```
li {
 list-style-image: url('/imagepath.png');
}
```

This can still go in your head tag without editing the markup of the list.

Comment: Found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563344/how-can-i-increase-the-bullet-size-in-a-li.  I'll look more into it.  Although I can't use javascript either.  It's a really old app for special use.

Answer (score 0):

no way that I'm aware of.

but you could fake it by using :before

```
ul,li{list-style:none;}
li:before{content:"o";font-weight:bold;}
```

Comment: Thanks, Kae. It's for an IE6 site so can't use `before`

Answer (score 0):

put any background color for the (ex: .menu li a )tag  and add padding for that you will get like a box then border-radius and then for ( .menu li ) apply padding for left and right for spacing... (explained in reverse order)

```
#header .nav-primary ul li{float:left;display:block;margin:0;padding:0 22px;}
#header .nav-primary ul li a{text-decoration:none;color:#030;background:#CBCBCB;border-radius:5px;padding:5px 0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for a solution to this too and found that if you nest a p inside li, you can style the bullets and bullet text separately.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><p>Hello</p></li>
  </ul>
</div

div ul li {
 /*this will style the bullets*/
}

div ul li p {
/*this will style the text*/
}
```