# cross browser issue aligning div and bullet styling

Tags: html, css

I have some html as below

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="LItms">
        <div class="clr">
        </div>
        <span>text con</span>
        <ul>
            <li>first</li>
            <li>second</li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I have some css for them

with out position relative

```
.clr {        
    color: red;    
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: square; 
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 16px;
    width:16px;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    margin-left: 23px;
}
```

with position relative

```
.clr {        
    color: red;
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: square; 
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 16px;
    width:16px;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    margin-left: 23px;
}
```

I tried both of them css, the issue is it work's fine in fire fox, but in chrome and ie, the size of bullet for div is smaller compared to firefox and even the space between 
bullet and span next to div with class .clr is more when compared to firefox, i want them to be aligned same accross the browsers ... any work around plz...........

Comment: please post a working fiddle of your problem.. [here is one](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/xVCjd/)

Comment: not sure of the final result you are trying to achieve, but you might try removing 'font-size: 40px;'. that at least makes it look the same in the different browsers. DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Fkpwt/1/

Comment: different browsers might have a little difference in default styling. Use a [Normalizer](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) it might help you.

Comment: Alexander, yes i know that it will look similar if i remove font-size, but i want to increase the bullet size.....as per my requirement

Comment: Then, yes as @avrahamcool mentions, Normalize, then try one of these other techniques for styling list bullet types. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450817/increase-size-of-list-style-bullet-type

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments,

> different browsers might have a little difference in default styling.
>   Use a [**Normalizer**](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers have different defaults. Reset everything using the following CSS at the very beginning of your CSS:

```
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
 }
```