# how to increase the font size of bullets of <li> in css?

Tags: css, html

A

B

c

D

E

how i will increase bullets without affecting the text?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450817/increase-size-of-list-style-bullet-type

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the content of your li with a span tag :

```css
li {
  font-size: 70px;
}
.li-content {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="li-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</span</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it will affect all the bullets in the page.

Comment: How i will particular bullet size increased.

Comment: Just add a class to the li tags tou want to target (example : class="big-bullet") and in css replace li for .big-bullet