# Decrease List style bullet size using css?

Tags: html, css

I searched at different sites but I can't get an actual solution for me. I want to decrease the size of bullet icon on li. But I don't wanna use the image at li:: before. Are there any ideas?

Comment: Although linked question is about changing bullet's color however methods described there are mostly generic can be used to fully customize list bullets.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457059/customize-list-item-bullets-using-css) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563344/how-can-i-increase-the-bullet-size-in-a-li) also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this, if you don't want to use image.

```css
li {
    list-style: none;
}

li:before {
    content:"· ";
    font-size:24px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a>Item 1</a></li>
<li><a>Item 2</a></li>
<li><a>Item 3</a></li>
<li><a>Item 4</a></li>
<li><a>Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you ! I found the actual solution ! cheers !

Answer (score 3):

[A solution drafted by W3C](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists/#text-markers) is to set a custom `list-style-type` property.

**This doesn't (yet) work on Safari or iOS Safari.** The [browser support of `list-style-type: <string>`](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_list-style-type_string) covers all other modern browsers.

---

One solution is to set a custom `list-style-type` for the `<ul>`, e.g. the bullet symbol • (`&bull;`) which is smaller than the default list bullet. Even smaller is the middot symbol · (`&middot;`).

[amp-what.com](https://www.amp-what.com) is a good resource for different symbols and also includes CSS codes for the symbols, e.g. the bullot symbol • is `\2022` in CSS and the middot symbol · is `\b7` in CSS.

```css
.small-bullets {
  list-style-type: '\2022';
  padding-left: 32px;
}

.small-bullets li {
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.even-smaller-bullets {
  list-style-type: '\b7';
  padding-left: 32px;
}

.even-smaller-bullets li {
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="default">
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
</ul>

<ul class="small-bullets">
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
</ul>

<ul class="even-smaller-bullets">
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a couple of ways

```
li{list-style-type:none;}
li:before{content:'\00b7'; font-size:20px; line-height:24px; vertical-align:middle;}
```

Or

```
li{list-style-type:none;}
```

And add a

```
<span>&#183;</span>
```

before the copy starts